# How to fix "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0180.5052.15' " in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing writing code in python, and the website from where I was learning made me do this project where I create receipts for customers who bought stuff at a fictional store.

I'm currently learning python on CodeAcademy, and when I ran the code it gave me an error for line 33. The original code in line 33 didn't convert the strings into floats, so I converted it into floats but it gave me a different error.

```
# description of item 1
lovely_loveseat_description = "Lovely Loveseat. Tufted polyester blend on wood. 32 inches high x 40 inches wide x 30 inches deep. Red or white."

# price of item 1
lovely_loveseat_price = "180.50"

# description of item 2
stylish_settee_description = "Stylish Settee. Faux leather on birch. 29.50 inches high x 54.75 inches wide x 28 inches deep. Black."

# price of item 2
stylish_settee_price = "180.50"

# description of item 3
luxurious_lamp_description = "Luxurious Lamp. Glass and iron. 36 inches tall. Brown with cream shade."

# price of item 3
luxurious_lamp_price = "52.15"

# sales tax is 8.8%
sales_tax = "0.088"

# second customer
customer_two_total = "0"

# customer 2 list of items
customer_two_itemization = "stylish_settee_description + luxurious_lamp_description"

# customer 2 total before tax
customer_two_total += stylish_settee_price
customer_two_total += luxurious_lamp_price

# customer 2 tax
customer_two_tax = float(customer_two_total) * float(sales_tax)

# customer 2 total after tax
customer_two_total += customer_two_tax

# customer 2 receipt
print("Customer Two Items:")
print(customer_two_itemization)
print("Customer Two Total:")
print(customer_two_total)
```

I couldn't figure out what I did wrong because it gave me this exact error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 33, in <module>
    customer_two_tax = float(customer_two_total) * float(sales_tax)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0180.5052.15'
```

Comment: Don't use double quotes when defining numeric variables. For example, change `lovely_loveseat_price = "180.50"` to `lovely_loveseat_price = 180.50`

Comment: The first thing any programming tutorial will teach is how to use _numbers_ (not strings) to perform simple arithmetic. Please read a tutorial before asking here.

Comment: Just looked it up, that seems to be a 'final project' of a pretty thorough python tutorial, guess OP was not paying attention to the explanations in the previous stages.